# Difference in ECDSA private key format

Tags: ssh, key, ecdsa

I have two private ssh keys, - one was originally created with ssh-keygen the other one with a python script. They are supposed to be the same, however one works for authentication and the other one doesn't.

After analyzing them with https://keytool.online/ and there seems to be one minor difference when comparing them in the OpenSSH format.

Explanation:

**1) Copy both keys in https://keytool.online/ in the ECDSA tab:**

Key 1 (Created with ssh-keygen)

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcCAQEEIBaYCj/CjZjq9aYehcvyejxqx5WVJ3OnfNbBq2+7iKyJoAoGCCqGSM49
AwEHoUQDQgAE1Rcx8Zo84aqSWqT/7i5NN7p+PI6dRfGdFFJapfcBlMhMjFsJkrxh
vncLphHuZHBoEILRMKf7hfVJ+tMwHMxQMA==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Key 2 (Created with python)

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgFpgKP8KNmOr1ph6F
y/J6PGrHlZUnc6d81sGrb7uIrImhRANCAATVFzHxmjzhqpJapP/uLk03un48jp1F
8Z0UUlql9wGUyEyMWwmSvGG+dwumEe5kcGgQgtEwp/uF9Un60zAczFAw
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**2) View them in the OpenSSH format:**

Key 1 (Created with ssh-keygen, in OpenSSH Format)

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAAAaAAAABNl
Y2RzYS1zaGEyLW5pc3RwMjU2AAAACG5pc3RwMjU2AAAAQQTVFzHxmjzhqpJapP/u
Lk03un48jp1F8Z0UUlql9wGUyEyMWwmSvGG+dwumEe5kcGgQgtEwp/uF9Un60zAc
zFAwAAAAsGt4wBFreMARAAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAy
NTYAAABBBNUXMfGaPOGqklqk/+4uTTe6fjyOnUXxnRRSWqX3AZTITIxbCZK8Yb53
C6YR7mRwaBCC0TCn+4X1SfrTMBzMUDAAAAAgFpgKP8KNmOr1ph6Fy/J6PGrHlZUn
c6d81sGrb7uIrIkAAAASZWNkc2Eta2V5LTIwMTkwOTIwAQIDBAUG
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Key 2 (Created with python, in OpenSSH Format)

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAAAaAAAABNl
Y2RzYS1zaGEyLW5pc3RwMjU2AAAACG5pc3RwMjU2AAAAQQTVFzHxmjzhqpJapP/u
Lk03un48jp1F8Z0UUlql9wGUyEyMWwmSvGG+dwumEe5kcGgQgtEwp/uF9Un60zAc
zFAwAAAAsFhPTMdYT0zHAAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAy
NTYAAABBBNUXMfGaPOGqklqk/+4uTTe6fjyOnUXxnRRSWqX3AZTITIxbCZK8Yb53
C6YR7mRwaBCC0TCn+4X1SfrTMBzMUDAAAAAgFpgKP8KNmOr1ph6Fy/J6PGrHlZUn
c6d81sGrb7uIrIkAAAASZWNkc2Eta2V5LTIwMTkwOTIwAQIDBAUG
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**3) Use a text difference viewing tool of your choice. You'll notice a few characters are different. What do they represent? What's the difference between both keys? All the domain parameters seem to be identical.**

Note the difference:
[image]

(The keys will not be used for anything important and have just been created to demonstrate this issue)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(I feel sure I've answered essentially this question before, but I can't find a dupe.)

OpenSSL partly created, and supports, *two* (or four depending how you count) types of PEM formats for private keys.

Your first file, with `BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY` (and no `Proc-type,DEK-Info` inside), is the 'traditional' or 'legacy' format which is specific to one algorithm, EC. It contains the private key in the format defined by [SEC1 from SECG](https://secg.org/) and also available as [rfc5915](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5915), then encoded/wrapped as 'PEM' i.e. base64 with linebreaks and header/trailer lines.

Your second file, with `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY`, is the 'new' (since about 2000!) PKCS8 format which is generic and covers all algorithms. Actual PKCS8 was first published by RSA Labs and has become harder to find since RSA was acquired by EMC and that by Dell but is also available as [rfc5208](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5208), again encoded/wrapped in PEM. This format (but not the legacy format) is among several PEM formats which are updated and restandardized in [rfc7468](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468) (see section 10, even though the TOC doesn't hyperlink it correctly!)

Both of these have unencrypted and encrypted variants, which some people count separately (hence my two or four). Your Q uses only unencrypted forms of these files, and also of the OpenSSH new format (more below).

Although formatted differently, they do contain the same key:

```
$ cat se218335.a; openssl pkey -in se218335.a -noout -text
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcCAQEEIBaYCj/CjZjq9aYehcvyejxqx5WVJ3OnfNbBq2+7iKyJoAoGCCqGSM49
AwEHoUQDQgAE1Rcx8Zo84aqSWqT/7i5NN7p+PI6dRfGdFFJapfcBlMhMjFsJkrxh
vncLphHuZHBoEILRMKf7hfVJ+tMwHMxQMA==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
Private-Key: (256 bit)
priv:
    16:98:0a:3f:c2:8d:98:ea:f5:a6:1e:85:cb:f2:7a:
    3c:6a:c7:95:95:27:73:a7:7c:d6:c1:ab:6f:bb:88:
    ac:89
pub:
    04:d5:17:31:f1:9a:3c:e1:aa:92:5a:a4:ff:ee:2e:
    4d:37:ba:7e:3c:8e:9d:45:f1:9d:14:52:5a:a5:f7:
    01:94:c8:4c:8c:5b:09:92:bc:61:be:77:0b:a6:11:
    ee:64:70:68:10:82:d1:30:a7:fb:85:f5:49:fa:d3:
    30:1c:cc:50:30
ASN1 OID: prime256v1

$ cat se218335.b; openssl pkey -in se218335.b -noout -text
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgFpgKP8KNmOr1ph6F
y/J6PGrHlZUnc6d81sGrb7uIrImhRANCAATVFzHxmjzhqpJapP/uLk03un48jp1F
8Z0UUlql9wGUyEyMWwmSvGG+dwumEe5kcGgQgtEwp/uF9Un60zAczFAw
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
Private-Key: (256 bit)
priv:
    16:98:0a:3f:c2:8d:98:ea:f5:a6:1e:85:cb:f2:7a:
    3c:6a:c7:95:95:27:73:a7:7c:d6:c1:ab:6f:bb:88:
    ac:89
pub:
    04:d5:17:31:f1:9a:3c:e1:aa:92:5a:a4:ff:ee:2e:
    4d:37:ba:7e:3c:8e:9d:45:f1:9d:14:52:5a:a5:f7:
    01:94:c8:4c:8c:5b:09:92:bc:61:be:77:0b:a6:11:
    ee:64:70:68:10:82:d1:30:a7:fb:85:f5:49:fa:d3:
    30:1c:cc:50:30
ASN1 OID: prime256v1
```

OpenSSH began using the OpenSSL legacy formats (RSA and DSA as well as EC) decades ago, and `ssh-keygen` has <s>never</s> only recently (8.1 in 2021-10) been upgraded to write PKCS8, although it *and* the `ssh` and `sshd` (and `ssh-add`) programs have been able to *read* PKCS8 since almost forever, because they actually call OpenSSL library routines that can handle both types. In particular after extracting the pubkey and configuring it, I can use *either* of your files to authenticate just fine:

```
$ ssh -i se218335.a localhost echo hi
hi
$ ssh -i se218335.b localhost echo hi
hi
```

If you are having a problem using the second file and want to solve it, you might ask about that.

---

Per comment by https://security.stackexchange.com/users/277838/westfarmer (even though it wasn't really in the Q):

OpenSSL can convert between the formats it implements (traditional and PKCS8), as well as PKCS12 which is not relevant here.

```
# any non-ancient OpenSSL:
openssl pkey <in >out # reads PKCS8 OR trad, encrypted or not, and writes PKCS8 unencrypted
openssl pkey <in >out -$cipher # e.g. -aes128 same but writes PKCS8 encrypted
# OpenSSL 3.0.0 up
openssl pkey <in >out -traditional # reads any, writes traditional unencrypted
openssl pkey <in >out -traditional -$cipher # same but writes traditional encrypted
# all of the above work for all key types, not just EC(DSA)
# (although OpenSSH cannot use OpenSSL-format key for Ed25519)
# and where the input and/or output is encrypted you are prompted for the password(s)
# or you can specify -passin arg and/or -passout arg per the man page on your system 
# or at https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-passphrase-options.html 

# OpenSSL below 3.0.0, for EC (which can actually be ECDSA, ECDH, ECMQV) only
openssl ec <in >out # reads any, writes traditional=SEC1 unencrypted
openssl ec <in >out -$cipher # same, writes traditional=SEC1 encrypted
```

`ssh-keygen` can read traditional or PKCS8 OR since 6.5 OpenSSH's 'new' format with labels `BEGIN/END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY` as shown in the Q and analyzed in [the other answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/218353/39571); it can write traditional (except for Ed25519) since forever but in 7.8 up you must specify `-m PEM`, PKCS8 since 8.1 if you use `-m PKCS8`, or new format since 6.5 if you specify `-o` and since 7.8 by default. To get it to convert a keyfile just run it with the options `-p -f $file` to change the password; it reads whatever format the input is in, and writes whatever format you specify or allow to default, encrypted if you specify a password and unencrypted if you enter an empty string (just hit return). You can use options `-P 'old' -N 'new'` instead of being prompted. If the input is encrypted and you specify the new password to be the same as the old, you haven't really changed the password but you have rewritten the file in a possibly-different format. `ssh-keygen` can also import or export the *public* key in the rfc4716 format used by the 'commercial' SSH, ssh.com aka Tectia.

For near-completeness, the `puttygen` utility in the [PuTTY suite](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty) can, in addition to generating keys, convert between (most or all of) the OpenSSH formats plus PuTTY's own 'PPK' format AND the ssh.com/Tectia format (which are both different yet again). puttygen works (very) differently between Windows and Unix/Linux and exactly what conversions and cases it supports have changed between versions, so investigating that is left (for now?) as an exercise.

Comment: You are right. Indeed, I was handlnig the same thing just few months back and missed the EC part in the header. But note that you have also slight inaccuracy in your answer. We recently we made a change in openssh so it is able to generate the pkcs8 files: https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3013 (not yet in released version of openssh).

Comment: Thanks for the warning, although I almost never have time to look at prerelease versions, and often take a month or so to catch up even on releases. It would be nice if 'you' (someone) could also fix the name for _pubkey_ `ssh-keygen -e/i -m pkcs8` which is really X.509/PKIX and now 7468 sec 13, not PKCS8/5208 at all -- I've had trouble explaining that to users.

Comment: I think this will be harder. The PKCS8 is historically something known. There is already one key format `RFC4716` and adding one more `RFC7468` would sound even more confusing. But feel free to comment on the openssh bugzilla, open a new bug with your reasoning.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for the in-depth explanation. Very much appreciated. I also managed to authenticate now - the issue there was something else (mis-configured permissions on the .ssh directory). But still handy to know about the new and the legacy format of the key files. I wonder why `ssh-keygen` has not been updated to write PKCS8.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 nice answer, can you tell how to convert these two formats to each other， thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The encoding of the OpenSSH keys is just base64 so once they do not have passphrase, you can analyze the content.

The first one:

```
$ base64 -d | hexdump -C
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAAAaAAAABNl
Y2RzYS1zaGEyLW5pc3RwMjU2AAAACG5pc3RwMjU2AAAAQQTVFzHxmjzhqpJapP/u
Lk03un48jp1F8Z0UUlql9wGUyEyMWwmSvGG+dwumEe5kcGgQgtEwp/uF9Un60zAc
zFAwAAAAsGt4wBFreMARAAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAy
NTYAAABBBNUXMfGaPOGqklqk/+4uTTe6fjyOnUXxnRRSWqX3AZTITIxbCZK8Yb53
C6YR7mRwaBCC0TCn+4X1SfrTMBzMUDAAAAAgFpgKP8KNmOr1ph6Fy/J6PGrHlZUn
c6d81sGrb7uIrIkAAAASZWNkc2Eta2V5LTIwMTkwOTIwAQIDBAUG
00000000  6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2d  6b 65 79 2d 76 31 00 00  |openssh-key-v1..|
00000010  00 00 04 6e 6f 6e 65 00  00 00 04 6e 6f 6e 65 00  |...none....none.|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00  00 00 68 00 00 00 13 65  |..........h....e|
00000030  63 64 73 61 2d 73 68 61  32 2d 6e 69 73 74 70 32  |cdsa-sha2-nistp2|
00000040  35 36 00 00 00 08 6e 69  73 74 70 32 35 36 00 00  |56....nistp256..|
00000050  00 41 04 d5 17 31 f1 9a  3c e1 aa 92 5a a4 ff ee  |.A...1..<...Z...|
00000060  2e 4d 37 ba 7e 3c 8e 9d  45 f1 9d 14 52 5a a5 f7  |.M7.~<..E...RZ..|
00000070  01 94 c8 4c 8c 5b 09 92  bc 61 be 77 0b a6 11 ee  |...L.[...a.w....|
00000080  64 70 68 10 82 d1 30 a7  fb 85 f5 49 fa d3 30 1c  |dph...0....I..0.|
00000090  cc 50 30 00 00 00 b0 6b  78 c0 11 6b 78 c0 11 00  |.P0....kx..kx...|
000000a0  00 00 13 65 63 64 73 61  2d 73 68 61 32 2d 6e 69  |...ecdsa-sha2-ni|
000000b0  73 74 70 32 35 36 00 00  00 08 6e 69 73 74 70 32  |stp256....nistp2|
000000c0  35 36 00 00 00 41 04 d5  17 31 f1 9a 3c e1 aa 92  |56...A...1..<...|
000000d0  5a a4 ff ee 2e 4d 37 ba  7e 3c 8e 9d 45 f1 9d 14  |Z....M7.~<..E...|
000000e0  52 5a a5 f7 01 94 c8 4c  8c 5b 09 92 bc 61 be 77  |RZ.....L.[...a.w|
000000f0  0b a6 11 ee 64 70 68 10  82 d1 30 a7 fb 85 f5 49  |....dph...0....I|
00000100  fa d3 30 1c cc 50 30 00  00 00 20 16 98 0a 3f c2  |..0..P0... ...?.|
00000110  8d 98 ea f5 a6 1e 85 cb  f2 7a 3c 6a c7 95 95 27  |.........z<j...'|
00000120  73 a7 7c d6 c1 ab 6f bb  88 ac 89 00 00 00 12 65  |s.|...o........e|
00000130  63 64 73 61 2d 6b 65 79  2d 32 30 31 39 30 39 32  |cdsa-key-2019092|
00000140  30 01 02 03 04 05 06                              |0......|
```

The second one:

```
$ base64 -d | hexdump -C
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAAAaAAAABNl
Y2RzYS1zaGEyLW5pc3RwMjU2AAAACG5pc3RwMjU2AAAAQQTVFzHxmjzhqpJapP/u
Lk03un48jp1F8Z0UUlql9wGUyEyMWwmSvGG+dwumEe5kcGgQgtEwp/uF9Un60zAc
zFAwAAAAsFhPTMdYT0zHAAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAy
NTYAAABBBNUXMfGaPOGqklqk/+4uTTe6fjyOnUXxnRRSWqX3AZTITIxbCZK8Yb53
C6YR7mRwaBCC0TCn+4X1SfrTMBzMUDAAAAAgFpgKP8KNmOr1ph6Fy/J6PGrHlZUn
c6d81sGrb7uIrIkAAAASZWNkc2Eta2V5LTIwMTkwOTIwAQIDBAUG
00000000  6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2d  6b 65 79 2d 76 31 00 00  |openssh-key-v1..|
00000010  00 00 04 6e 6f 6e 65 00  00 00 04 6e 6f 6e 65 00  |...none....none.|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00  00 00 68 00 00 00 13 65  |..........h....e|
00000030  63 64 73 61 2d 73 68 61  32 2d 6e 69 73 74 70 32  |cdsa-sha2-nistp2|
00000040  35 36 00 00 00 08 6e 69  73 74 70 32 35 36 00 00  |56....nistp256..|
00000050  00 41 04 d5 17 31 f1 9a  3c e1 aa 92 5a a4 ff ee  |.A...1..<...Z...|
00000060  2e 4d 37 ba 7e 3c 8e 9d  45 f1 9d 14 52 5a a5 f7  |.M7.~<..E...RZ..|
00000070  01 94 c8 4c 8c 5b 09 92  bc 61 be 77 0b a6 11 ee  |...L.[...a.w....|
00000080  64 70 68 10 82 d1 30 a7  fb 85 f5 49 fa d3 30 1c  |dph...0....I..0.|
00000090  cc 50 30 00 00 00 b0 58  4f 4c c7 58 4f 4c c7 00  |.P0....XOL.XOL..|
000000a0  00 00 13 65 63 64 73 61  2d 73 68 61 32 2d 6e 69  |...ecdsa-sha2-ni|
000000b0  73 74 70 32 35 36 00 00  00 08 6e 69 73 74 70 32  |stp256....nistp2|
000000c0  35 36 00 00 00 41 04 d5  17 31 f1 9a 3c e1 aa 92  |56...A...1..<...|
000000d0  5a a4 ff ee 2e 4d 37 ba  7e 3c 8e 9d 45 f1 9d 14  |Z....M7.~<..E...|
000000e0  52 5a a5 f7 01 94 c8 4c  8c 5b 09 92 bc 61 be 77  |RZ.....L.[...a.w|
000000f0  0b a6 11 ee 64 70 68 10  82 d1 30 a7 fb 85 f5 49  |....dph...0....I|
00000100  fa d3 30 1c cc 50 30 00  00 00 20 16 98 0a 3f c2  |..0..P0... ...?.|
00000110  8d 98 ea f5 a6 1e 85 cb  f2 7a 3c 6a c7 95 95 27  |.........z<j...'|
00000120  73 a7 7c d6 c1 ab 6f bb  88 ac 89 00 00 00 12 65  |s.|...o........e|
00000130  63 64 73 61 2d 6b 65 79  2d 32 30 31 39 30 39 32  |cdsa-key-2019092|
00000140  30 01 02 03 04 05 06                              |0......|
00000147
```

The key format is described in the [OpenSSH repository](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/src/usr.bin/ssh/PROTOCOL.key?annotate=HEAD).

The difference here is that one key has the following bytes `6b 78 c0 11 6b 78 c0 11` and the other `58 4f 4c c7 58 4f 4c c7`. These bytes represent two random 32B integers that are same and that are used for verification that the deciphered key is really valid (in case of there is used encryption). See the `checkint` field in the linked document.

Both of the keys are valid according to the specification (in OpenSSH key format).

For the difference of the PEM format, see the dave_thompson_085's answer. TLDR, one of them is legacy PEM and the other is modern PKCS# 8 format including the same key, where both of them are understood by OpenSSH.

Comment: Correct for the OpenSSH files, not for the others.